# Which data format to publish data from Vantage Pro 2 weather station?

Tags: xml, json, weather, data-formats, opendata

I'm looking for a **standard data format** which can be used to publish weather [data collected](http://www.davisnet.com/product_documents/weather/manuals/07395-234_IM_06312.pdf) by a [Davis Instrument Vantage Pro 2 weather station](http://www.davisnet.com/weather/products/vantage-pro-professional-weather-stations.asp).

This is in order to comply to openData movement.

Do you have any JSON/XML/other standard data format that VP2 data should follow to publish its data ?

Comment: If you're interested in Open Data, have you considered contributing to [Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org)? They have [clear instructions](http://openweathermap.org/stations) on how to setup your device with their API and what sort of format they want the data in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [CF Metadata Convention](http://cf-pcmdi.llnl.gov/). It is a convention "designed to promote the processing and sharing of files created with the [NetCDF API](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/index.html)." NetCDF is a format that can be aware of units, datums, timezones, etc. and CF ensures that this metadata is all coherent.